# does filebeat support aknowledgment in tcp input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, websocket, tcp, filebeat

In my rails project, I need to deploy elk and filebeat as my log system, As I know filebeat could support TCP input, and because every log is important in my project I have real-time input and I choose socket as input configuration for filebeat. everything going well till I found some things, I deploy my rails project in AWS, Aws sends logs with socket very well but it needs ack flags to check when should send the next logs message. as I know logstash, elasticsearch and kibana have some kind of queue that when reading message return to tool witch is stay before them that get the new message and wait for a new one but in the case of filebeat and socket I could not found any things, Does anyone knows how filebeat tell to socket that get any new message and wait for next one?